# mysql... compare and match items in same column

Tags: mysql

I have a column full of server names. For example;

```
LouServer01
VgsServer01
LouServer02
VgsServer02
```

I need/want to be able to create a query that can match those two names based on everything after Lou/Vgs and give me something that looks like this:

```
Louisville  | Vegas
____________|____________
LouServer01 | VgsServer01
LouServer02 | VgsServer02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server naming format/convention is fixed then you can get desired output using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
       MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(name, 3) = 'Lou' THEN name END) Louisville,
       MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(name, 3) = 'Vgs' THEN name END) Vegas
  FROM servers
 GROUP BY RIGHT(name, 2)
```

Output:

```
|  LOUISVILLE |       VEGAS |
|-------------|-------------|
| LouServer01 | VgsServer01 |
| LouServer02 | VgsServer02 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82b83a5/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query you need

```
SELECT
    Louisville.name LouisvilleServer,
    Vegas.name VegasServer
FROM
(
    SELECT name,SUBSTR(name,LOCATE('0',name)) num FROM servers
    WHERE LEFT(name,LOCATE('0',name)-1)='LouServer'
) Louisville
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name,SUBSTR(name,LOCATE('0',name)) num FROM servers
    WHERE LEFT(name,LOCATE('0',name)-1)='VgsServer'
) Vegas
ON Louisville.num = Vegas.num;
```

Here is a sample table

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS servers;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE servers
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name VARCHAR(20),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ->     KEY (name)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO servers (name) VALUES
    -> ('LouServer01'),('VgsServer01'),
    -> ('LouServer02'),('VgsServer02');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM servers;
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | LouServer01 |
|  3 | LouServer02 |
|  2 | VgsServer01 |
|  4 | VgsServer02 |
+----+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the query you need executed

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     Louisville.name LouisvilleServer,
    ->     Vegas.name VegasServer
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT name,SUBSTR(name,LOCATE('0',name)) num FROM servers
    ->     WHERE LEFT(name,LOCATE('0',name)-1)='LouServer'
    -> ) Louisville
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT name,SUBSTR(name,LOCATE('0',name)) num FROM servers
    ->     WHERE LEFT(name,LOCATE('0',name)-1)='VgsServer'
    -> ) Vegas
    -> ON Louisville.num = Vegas.num;
+------------------+-------------+
| LouisvilleServer | VegasServer |
+------------------+-------------+
| LouServer01      | VgsServer01 |
| LouServer02      | VgsServer02 |
+------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Excellent! How can the query be edited to match anything after "Lou" and "Vgs" ?

Comment: Please specify what `match anything after Lou and Vgs` means ? Do you have a complete list of servers I can see ???